# R - finding max value of Corpus vector

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, corpus

I'm new to R coding. 
I've been trying to use the TM library to get the percentage of sentiment in each element.

I started by using the:

```
   sc <- Corpus(VectorSource(email))
```

After that is tried to minimize the unnecessary words by using the:

```
sclean<- tm_map(sc, removePunctuation)
sclean <- tm_map(sclean, content_transformer(tolower))
sclean <- tm_map(sclean, removeWords, stopwords(kind="en"))
sclean <- tm_map(sclean, removeNumbers)
sclean <- tm_map(sclean, stripWhitespace)
sclean <- tm_map(sclean, removeWords, commonwords)
sent<-sent_Analysed<-get_nrc_sentiment(unlist(as.list(sclean)))
```

I'm getting an answer that looks like (each row is a "sent" ):

[image: feelings]

From this i want to find the maximum value and calculate the percentage of it (excluding the negative and positive).
For example for line 2:

The max value will be: trust (40) 
And the percentage will be: 32.5 ( max / sum (= 123) * 100)

I'm struggling with finding the max value, and the sum (each line is printed by a for loop) of all numbers without the last 2 columns

Comment: It would be great if you could make this example reproducible. For example, we don't know what your `email` object looks like or what your `get_nrc_sentiment` function does. We also don't know what sort of object `sent` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a smaller example than yours...

```
sent <- data.frame(a1=c(1,2),a2=c(2,3),a3=c(4,1))
sent
  a1 a2 a3
1  1  2  4
2  2  3  1
```

You can do this in base R using `apply` as follows...

```
sentsum <- data.frame(best=names(sent)[apply(sent,1,which.max)], #name of highest column
                      score=apply(sent,1,max), #value of highest column
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
sentsum$percent <- 100*sentsum$score/rowSums(sent) #percent of row sum

sentsum
  best score  percent
1   a3     4 57.14286
2   a2     3 50.00000
```

Comment: Thank you! that is almost all, is it possible to eliminate the last 2 columns of each vector? Because i don't want the "negative" "positive" columns will interfere in the calculation of this one

Comment: The easiest way is probably to define `sent2 <- sent[,1:(ncol(sent)-2)]` and work with that instead.

Comment: That made it. Thank you!